# UITableView with UIButtons as UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've noticed in some apps, like the Contacts app, there's a button or buttons at the bottom of a Grouped Table View.  I was wondering if those buttons are part of the UITableView, like the button is in a UITableViewCell, or if it's a UIView that has a button in it that's below the UITableView.  I was also wondering if either method was better than the other.  I want to add some buttons to my UITableView similar to the Contacts app and didn't know what the better approach would be.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` has two relevant properties, `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView`. All you have to do to replicate what you're seeing in Contacts is connect the property to a custom `UIView` that contains a `UIButton` as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar things about add UIButtons to UITableView. 
You can add the button as a part in the UITableViewCell, or, you can make a custom view as the `footer view` of UITableView.